# Understanding Laravel Session Handler

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to understand Laravels session handler and can't find anything online.  At the moment, in `session.php` I am doing

```
'lifetime' => 10,
```

I have the session driver set to file.  So from what I have read, this sets the idle timeout of the session to 10 minutes.

So what does idle mean in this case?  I am assuming it means if no request is sent to the server within 10 minutes it will expire.  Is this correct?

Also, how can it tell if no request has been sent within 10 minutes?  I have taken a look at the session file within storage, and I do not see any timestamp.

So how exactly does all of this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct: if you don't send any request after the lifetime config value the session will be destroyed.

The `Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler` class has a `gc()` function, it is a garbage collector function that has a probability to be called on every request, you can control the chances with the `session.lottery` config value. This function destroy each session file that has a modified timestamp older than now - lifetime.

You can find the `Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler` class in the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/FileSessionHandler.php` if you want to take a look at the source code.

Comment: The gc is not called on every request. See `collectGarbage` in `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession`. The modified time of the session file is compared to determine if the session is valid. See `filemtime($path) >= Carbon::now()->subMinutes($this->minutes)->getTimestamp()` in `Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler`

Comment: @adam you're right, the gc() has a probability to run on every request and the compare si based on the modified timestamp. I'll edit the answer, thank you.